# How to setup nested models with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4 to build a question and answers type of application.

Should the models I create be:

```
Question
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answers

Answer
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
```

Or should it be:

```
Question
QuestionAnswer
```

Comment: If there would be another `Answer` model then you can put this one into `Question` model. So it would be like `Question::Answer`.

Comment: This is really up to you, and I don't think it's worth asking a question for it. However, I'd say you should go with the first option, because it'll give you `question.answers` association which is much nicer than what the second option would give you, which is `question.question_answers`. Still, this is not a very big deal since you can always customize the association name to make it whatever you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's based on your preference on choosing the names of the tables, but having simply `questions` and `answers` tables are readable and makes sense when you call associated methods like say `Question.last.answers` rather than `Question.last.question_answers` (no duplicates).

Furthermore, `QuestionAnswer` looks more like something you use to represent a join model `question_answers` on a `has_many through` association.

```
# models/question.rb
# database table - questions
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answers
end

# models/answer.rb
# database table - answers (question_id as foreign key)
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :questions
end
```

However, it is really up to you how you want to model your data.